# Lubuntu USB full install but all changes to external harddrive

Tags: usb, lubuntu, external-hdd

I have a damaged hdd. It is not working anymore (I tried low-level formating etc...) And I want to install lubuntu on my usb drive. but I want to keep my changes on my external hdd.

Or;
Is there any chance to install lubuntu on my ext hdd without losing data

Answer (score 0):

If the pc boots off usb you can install directly to the external hard drive and boot entirely off that. However acessing everything off a usb drive will work but will be slightly slow compared to new sata drives. If you have a usb flash drive you could use live session and save everything to to the hard drive but this would not get latest security updates. You could make a /home partition on the usb hard drive but you will not get security updates on the usb flash drive without persitance. Also usb flash drives as flash memory are limited in the number of writes and do not get the speed of say a sata solid state drive because at there low price point and to use only enough power to run of usb they do not have the best controller to get the data stored electrictally in the nand cells.

What I would do is just run everything off the external hard drive. Running a / partition on the a smaller flash drive will probably result in wearing the flash drive out over prolonged use. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling is minimal on these usb drives as they are generally to like save photos to transfer files not designed to run an operating system on but they are inexpensive and small.

With that in mind I would end up booting the live installer to the external hard drive removing other disks as this can make things more complicated if the installer. However most extenral hard drives purchased from stores come ntfs formatted for windows or sometimes there are ones for mac os X with hfs + with one partiton for the entire drive. I would still want another backup copy of my data. I think taking out the broken hard drive may make things easier if you can open the case of the machine. And if it detects the install on the internal it might try to dual boot the internal drive and external drive which leads to a more complicated setup and is more error prone. Then I would physically remove the bad hard drive as it will only waste power or make things trikier by trying to save the disk. I recommend selecting something else at the installer at this step. If you do not have any data kept on the external hard drive and you had say another backup say on another external hard drive you could delete the entire ntfs partition and replace it with ext4 the defualt. Or you could leave the ntfs partition if you interface with windows computers a lot and want to still be able to tranfer files to it normally. Over usb resizing the partitions can take quite a while. When selecting manual partitioning you will also get to choose the bootloader. You do not want to select the small usb flash normally unless you have problems booting from the external hard disk.

enter your information and install like you normally would and then reboot press enter remove the usb. In bios or uefi you want to set the machine to boot from usb as defualt. However sometimes external hard disks that are the small 2.5 inch laptop drives booting off usb can cause situations where the drive is not initalized at startup and it does not load the bootloader properly from the hard disk. On my 1 tb seagate expansion drives I find sometimes it has enough power to initlize the drives on reboot but not from booting when powered off. However if you keep the usb flash drive as the live session and then reboot remove that you can get it to boot of this external laptop drive. If you had say an desktop external hard drive with a power cord that plugged into the wall then it would gets its power through that and not be complicated. Once you boot from the hard disk you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks for the reply I shrinked my exthdd ntfs partition and created 100gb ext4. My real point in op is "is shrinking ntfs partition damages data". Sorry not to be clear English is not my native language. My only problem is grub can't be run in boot my exthdd drive. For booting, I use my lubuntu usb drive which I used use and full installed. I just updated parameters to recognise my lubuntu on exthdd. But is there a way to boot directly only with my exthdd?

Comment: I should have said might. I am not sure sometimes it might not be lubuntus  fault if the drive does not show the bootloader to the bios on the external. Does it not see the install or does grub load and give an error message. I sometimes got devices not found and grub boots into rescue mode. The workaround I remembered for that was from the live sesssion grub install --recheck on the device that is your external hard drive. But if the bios does not see it as a bootable device I am not sure of how to solve that.

Comment: bios can see my device as a bootable device. There is a grub error. I can't remember clearly but it's like "unsupported filesystem" ... I installed grub to sda (which is my exthdd) then I installed sda5 (my lubuntu partition) after I got this error but everything is same. I thought grub can't be load because of ntfs fs but it gave same error on ext4 too